# Why is my more complicated C loop faster?

Tags: c, performance, assembly

I am looking at the performance of `memchr`-like functions and made an interesting observation.

This is `check.c` with 3 implementations to find the offset of a `\n` character in a string:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t mem1(const char *s)
{
  const char *p = s;
  while (1)
  {
    const char x = *p;
    if (x == '\n') return (p - s);
    p++;
  }
}

size_t mem2(const char *s)
{
  const char *p = s;
  while (1)
  {
    const char x = *p;
    if (x <= '$' && (x == '\n' || x == '\0')) return (p - s);
    p++;
  }
}

size_t mem3(const char *s)
{
  const char *p = s;
  while (1)
  {
    const char x = *p;
    if (x == '\n' || x == '\0') return (p - s);
    p++;
  }
}

size_t mem4(const char *s)
{
  const char *p = s;
  while (1)
  {
    const char x = *p;
    if (x <= '$' && (x == '\n')) return (p - s);
    p++;
  }
}
```

I run these functions on a string of bytes which can be described by the Haskell expression `(concat $ replicate 10000 "abcd") ++ "\n" ++ "hello"` - that is 10000 times `asdf`, then the newline to find, and then `hello`. Of course all 3 implementations return the same offset: 40000 as expected.

Interestingly, when compiled with `gcc -O2`, the run times on that string are:

- `mem1`: 16 us
- `mem2`: 12 us
- `mem3`: 25 us
- `mem4`: 16 us

(I'm using the [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) library to measure these times with statistical accuracy.)

I cannot explain this to myself. Why is `mem2` so much faster than the other two?

--

The assembly as generated by `gcc -S -O2 -o check.asm check.c`:

```
mem1:
.LFB14:
  cmpb  $10, (%rdi)
  movq  %rdi, %rax
  je  .L9
.L6:
  addq  $1, %rax
  cmpb  $10, (%rax)
  jne .L6
  subq  %rdi, %rax
  ret
.L9:
  xorl  %eax, %eax
  ret


mem2:
.LFB15:
  movq  %rdi, %rax
  jmp .L13
.L19:
  cmpb  $10, %dl
  je  .L14
.L11:
  addq  $1, %rax
.L13:
  movzbl  (%rax), %edx
  cmpb  $36, %dl
  jg  .L11
  testb %dl, %dl
  jne .L19
.L14:
  subq  %rdi, %rax
  ret


mem3:
.LFB16:
  movzbl  (%rdi), %edx
  testb %dl, %dl
  je  .L26
  cmpb  $10, %dl
  movq  %rdi, %rax
  jne .L27
  jmp .L26
.L30:
  cmpb  $10, %dl
  je  .L23
.L27:
  addq  $1, %rax
  movzbl  (%rax), %edx
  testb %dl, %dl
  jne .L30
.L23:
  subq  %rdi, %rax
  ret
.L26:
  xorl  %eax, %eax
  ret


mem4:
.LFB17:
  cmpb  $10, (%rdi)
  movq  %rdi, %rax
  je  .L38
.L36:
  addq  $1, %rax
  cmpb  $10, (%rax)
  jne .L36
  subq  %rdi, %rax
  ret
.L38:
  xorl  %eax, %eax
  ret
```

Any explanation is very appreciated!

Comment: And how does `while (*p != '\n' && *p != '\0') ++p; return p - s;` fare? :P

Comment: @EdHeal This is not one execution. As mentioned, I used [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion), which runs my code a few hundred thousand times and measures the statistical significance of the results. A criterion report [looks like this](http://bos.github.io/criterion/)

Comment: @cHao `while (*p != '\n' && *p != '\0') ++p; return p - s;` performs as `mem3`, 25 us.

Comment: Now, as you're on x86, try to write something that compiles to REPNE SCASB ;)

Comment: @nh2: Your report verifies this?

Comment: Also, for a really fair test, tweak the linker to make sure none of the loops crosses a cache line boundary.

Comment: @Notlikethat Considering assembly string instructions: If I wanted to make a `mem*` function as fast as possible, yes (thanks for the pointer), but currently I'm trying to understand why the performance of these normal loops are so unexpected (I would expect `mem1` to be fastest or equal since its assembly loop is smallest).

Comment: @Notlikethat Can you give me a pointer about how to tune the linker as you suggest?

Comment: @cHao Yes, I just tried it

Comment: @nh2 With GCC you can use [__attribute__((aligned(64)))](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) on the functions, or just compile with -falign-functions=64, assuming your cache lines are 64 bytes (mine are on this old Core 2 Duo). These functions should be small enough to fit, otherwise you have to resort to even more trickery to try and get just the critical loop code within a single cache line.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks. I tried `-falign-functions=64` (I have an i5-2520M), but the timings are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is it's to do with register dependency - if you look at the 3-instruction main loop in `mem1`, you have a circular dependency on `rax`. Naïvely, this means each instruction *has* to wait for the last one to finish - in practice it means if the instructions aren't retired quickly enough the microarchitecture may run out of registers to rename and just give up and stall for a bit.

In `mem2` the fact that there are 4 instructions in the loop - and possibly also the fact that there's more of an explicit pipeline in the use of both `rax` and `edx/dl` - is probably giving the out-of-order execution hardware an easier time thus it ends up pipelining *more* efficiently.

I don't claim to be an expert so this *may* be complete nonsense, but based on what I've studied of [Agner Fog's absolute goldmine of Intel optimisation details](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) it doesn't seem an entirely unreasonable hypothesis.

Edit: Out of interest, I've tested `mem1` and `mem2` on my machine (Core 2 Duo E7500), compiled with -O2 -falign-functions=64 to the exact same assembly code. Calling either function with the given string 1,000,000 times in a loop and using Linux's `time`, I get ~19s for `mem1` and ~18.8s for `mem2` - much less than the 25% difference on the newer microarchitecture. Guess it's time to buy an i5...

Answer (score 2):

Your input is such that makes `mem2` faster. Every letter in the input apart from '\n' has value larger than '$', so `if` condition is false from the first part of the expression (x <= '$'), and second part of the expression (x == '\n' || x == '\0') is never executed. If you would use "####" instead of "abcd" I suspect the execution would become slower.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be it: `if (x <= '$' && (x == '\n'))` still lets your argument hold, but it performs like `mem1` (16 us). I am adding it now as `mem4`.

Answer (score 1):

With a cache, the test of `mem1()` takes the brunt of filling the cache.

Run the `mem1()` test first and again as last and use the 2nd time as it reflects a primed cache like the other tests.  Confident it will be faster and a more fair time comparison.

Comment: Tried this, it has no effect, nor does the order in which I run the tests in general. Not sure what you mean with "filling the cache" given that each function is ran hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: @nh2 I was suspecting the data set was in variant locations and it is the caching of that data and not the code itself that I hope would realize a difference.